# Copy every file in a directory structure into specific path only if file does not exist there already

Tags: command-line, bash, files, find

Would like to copy every file from a directory structure to a specific directory only if file does not exist there already.

Got the first part from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800989/copy-every-file-of-entire-directory-structure-into-base-path-of-another#):

```
find . -type f -exec cp {} /target-directory \;
```

How can I check if the file exists or not? If not, copy the file, otherwise skip.

Comment: Do you mean "copy all files in the source tree into a  (specific) single directory with no subdirectories"? Or "copy all files in the source tree into a subdirectory of the destination directory similar to where it was in the source tree"? I read the question as the first case - can you edit the question to clarify? (I know you have your answer, but it will be read, and used, by others.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `-u` switch from `cp` command:

> copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing

or use `rsync` command with `--ignore-existing`:

> skip updating files that exist on receiver

Example:

```
rsync --ignore-existing source/* destination/
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original command can be rewritten as:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'test -e /target-directory/"$1" || cp "$1" /target-directory' sh {} \;
```

The key here is that we call shell with specific commands and pass found file as `$1` argument. If `test -e /target-directory/"$1"` fails, that means file doesn't exist, in which case `cp` will copy the file.

In general, one can use other commands, as long as the command can verify existence of a file. Some of the other alternatives:

- `/usr/bin/realpath -e /target-directory/"$1" > /dev/null || cp "$1" /target-directory`
- `stat >/dev/null /target-directory/"$1" || cp  "$1" /target-directory/"$1"`

Comment: Why `stat` to test for file existence in Bash? Wouldn't `test -e` be much simpler?

Comment: @DavidFoerster No particular reason.  test command will do too. I'll edit my answer later if i don't forget

Answer (score 0):

Read `man cp`, and use the `--no-clobber` option to `cp`.